# Can I sort IPython completions in the VS Code terminal by usefulness rather than alphabetically?

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, ipython

The IPython terminal in VS Code gives options sorted alphabetically (see image #1 below) when I press tab inside a function (any function, custom or from a standard library). This list contains inbuilt python functions, error types, user variables and imports, so by default has over 100 items.

[image: autocomplete options list with alphabetical sorting]

In a regular python file or Jupyter notebook the autocomplete options are sorted not alphabetically, but by relevance: arguments of that function and variables in the same file come first, followed by other options. Is there a way I can change the autocomplete option list sorting in the IPython terminal?

[image: autocomplete options sorted (at least partially) by relevance]

I've seen a bunch of questions asking how to get autocomplete to work but haven't found anything relating to this issue.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541, [ask]. show what you expect to see.

Comment: Thanks - good point, have included another image showing what I expect (would have to type the lists out by hand to avoid including as images...)

Answer (score 0):

I expect that the answer is no. If my understanding is correct, these are largely separate completion/suggestion systems. One is IPython, and one is the Python/Jupyter extensions for VS Code, working with the VS Code extension API.

I tried to see if [IPython has settings](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/whatsnew/version7.html) for sorting the possible completion results, but couldn't find one (at the time of this writing). [The IPython docs say that](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/integrating.html#tab-completion):

> To change the attributes displayed by tab-completing your object, define a `__dir__(self)` method for it. For more details, see the documentation of the built-in [dir() function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir).
>
> You can also customise key completions for your objects, e.g. pressing tab after `obj["a`. To do so, define a method `_ipython_key_completions_()`, which returns a list of objects which are possible keys in a subscript expression `obj[key]`.

The closes thing I found for IPython was [`TerminalInteractiveShell.autosuggestions_provider`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/options/terminal.html#configtrait-TerminalInteractiveShell.autosuggestions_provider):

> Specifies from which source automatic suggestions are provided. Can be set to `'NavigableAutoSuggestFromHistory'` (<kbd>up</kbd> and <kbd>down</kbd> swap suggestions), `'AutoSuggestFromHistory'`, or None to disable automatic suggestions. Default is `'NavigableAutoSuggestFromHistory’`.

My understanding of VS Code's suggestion list ordering is that it's mostly based on some measure of match strength and optionally with a "locality bonus" (favouring suggesting things that are positioned close to the cared). See also the `sortText` property of [`CompletionItem`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CompletionItem) and feature requests like https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/74213 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/80444.