# Switching off word suggestions ('abc') in VSCode Python debug console

Tags: visual-studio-code

How is it possible to switch off word suggestions (those marked by 'abc' in the list of suggestions when typing) in the Python debug console in VSCode?

After setting `"editor.suggest.showWords": false` in VSCode 1.86.2, word suggestions still appear in the Python debug console.

Is there another way to switch them off?
Besides, is there a way to edit or delete the "cached" word suggestions?

Comment: reminds me of this ipython vscode terminal question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76739515/11107541, but it's probably not related since this isn't about ipython.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. So in case anybody has the same question, setting `"debug.console.historySuggestions": false` disables what I thought to be word suggestions, i.e., those marked by 'abc'.